# jQuery disable form to validate data

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable a login form for quick validating user data before submit to the server. My current code work nice; but the problem I am facing right now is, I need to click submit button 2 times to submit the form. My current code is:

```
$('#login-submit').click(function() {
  var nameId = '#' + $(this).attr('name');      // Form name
  submitForm(nameId);
});

function submitForm(nameId) {   
  var formId = nameId + '-form';        // Form id
  var email = nameId + '-email';        // Email
  var pwd = nameId + '-pwd';        // Password
  var btn = nameId + '-submit';     // Submit button

  $(formId).submit(function() { return false; });
  alert('click1');
  $(btn).on('click', function() {
    alert('click2');
    var emailVal = $(email).val();
    var pwdVal = $(pwd).val();

    /*alert(emailVal + " " + pwdVal);*/
    var isEmailValid = validateEmail(emailVal);
    var isPwdcValid = validatePwd(pwdVal);

    // Validate email
    if(!isEmailValid) { 
      $(email).addClass('error');
      $(email + '-error').show();
    } else {    
      $(email).removeClass('error');
      $(email + '-error').hide();
    }

    // Validate password
    if(!isPwdcValid) {
      $(pwd).addClass('error');
      $(pwd + '-error').show();
    } else {     
      $(pwd).removeClass('error');  
      $(pwd + '-error').hide();
    }

    if(isEmailValid && isPwdcValid) {
      $(btn).replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");
      var urlId = $(formId).attr('action');

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlId,
        data: $(formId).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {}
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The first time when I click submit button, it will alert 'click1' but not 'click2'. If I click the button again, the it will alert 'click2'. What should I do to get the alert for 'click2' with 1 button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code you are doing validation for one form,You don't required to call two event

Try below code for better one

HTML Part

```
 <span id="loginemail-error" style="display:none">email not valid</span>
 <span id="loginpwd-error" style="display: none">password not valid</span>
 <form name="myfrom" id="myform" method="post">
    Email: <input type="text" name="loginemail" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="loginpwd"/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login"/>
 </form>
```

Script Part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myform").on("submit",function(event){

        var $form = $(this);
        var values = {};
        hideError("loginemail");
        hideError("loginpwd");
        var err =false;
            $.each($form.serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
                            values[field.name] = field.value; // By you can access all field value by their name attribute
            });

           // alert(values.loginemail+" "+values.loginpwd);

            var emailVal = values.loginemail;
            var pwdVal   = values.loginpwd;

            var isEmailValid = validateEmail(emailVal);
            var isPwdcValid = validatePwd(pwdVal);

            if(!isEmailValid) 
            {
                showError("loginemail");
                err = true;
            }
            if(!isPwdcValid)
            {
                showError("loginpwd");
                err = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //youre ajax code
                err = false;
            }
           if(err)
           {
               return false;
           }
           else
           {
               return true;
           } 
    })

     function showError(fieldName)
     {
         $("input[name="+fieldName+"]").addClass('error');
         $("#"+fieldName+"-error").show();
     }
     function hideError(fieldName)
     {
         $("input[name="+fieldName+"]").removeClass('error');
         $("#"+fieldName+"-error").hide();
     }

     function validateEmail(emailVal)
     {
         alert(emailVal);
         if(emailVal==="myemail@gmail.com")
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }    
     }
     function validatePwd(pwdVal)
     {
          alert(pwdVal);
         if(pwdVal==="123456")
         {
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }    
     }

})

</script>
```