# Getting values from chosen form, when every form has the same class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I display data from my db using while loop. Everything works fine to time when I want to do something with forms inside this loops.

So this is how it looks like:

```
// RECORD NR 1
                    <div class=\"movie__btns\">
                    <form class=\"actionlist\" method=\"post\">
                            <select name=\"buttonaction\"  class=\"actionlist\" id=\"wybrana_opcja\">
                              <option value=\"watchlater\">Do obejrzenia</option>
                              <option value=\"watched\">Obejrzany</option>
                              <option value=\"favorite\">Ulubiony</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_user\" value=\"$stat[id]\">
                            <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_movie\" value=\"$podobny_film[id]\">
                                <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-md btn--warning\">Dodaj</button>                                        
                    </form>                             
                    </div>

// RECORD NR 2
                        <div class=\"movie__btns\">
                        <form class=\"actionlist\" method=\"post\">
                                <select name=\"buttonaction\"  class=\"actionlist\" id=\"wybrana_opcja\">
                                  <option value=\"watchlater\">Do obejrzenia</option>
                                  <option value=\"watched\">Obejrzany</option>
                                  <option value=\"favorite\">Ulubiony</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_user\" value=\"$stat[id]\">
                                <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_movie\" value=\"$podobny_film[id]\">
                                    <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-md btn--warning\">Dodaj</button>                                        
                        </form>                             
                        </div>
```

It looks this same but have different values in inputs.

And now, my problem:

**When I fill the second form, I will get id_movie value from first form.** How to fix it? I want value from second form, while submit second form.

My jQuery:

```
$('.actionlist').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var wybor = $("#wybrana_opcja option:selected" ).text();
        var id_user = $('.id_user').val();
        var id_movie = $('.id_movie').val();

});
```

Comment: you miss to add **name** attribute of the hidden id_movie in both forms! btw id_movie will the same in both forms

Comment: to get it in your js-function **var id_movie = $('.id_movie:first-child').val()** should work

Comment: No, id_movie are different in every form and that works in HTML. Have problem just with jQuery, want to get chosen form values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have both a `form` and `select` element with the `actionlist` class, so it'd be best to attach the event to the `form` only. You also need to remove the `id` attribute from the `select`, otherwise it will not be unique and render the page invalid.

Finally you can use the `form` referenced in the `this` keyword to find the related inputs:

```
$('form.actionlist').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var wybor = $form.find(".actionlist option:selected").text();
    var id_user = $form.find('.id_user').val();
    var id_movie = $form.find('.id_movie').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery "On" submit event

```
$("form.actionlist").on("submit",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   // your code
})
```

more reference how to get value check below answer

[jquery disable form to validate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644469/jquery-disable-form-to-validate-data/27645155#27645155)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class=\"movie__btns\" >
                <form class=\"actionlist\" method=\"post\">
                        <select name=\"buttonaction\"  class=\"actionlist\" id=\"wybrana_opcja\">
                          <option value=\"watchlater\">Do obejrzenia</option>
                          <option value=\"watched\">Obejrzany</option>
                          <option value=\"favorite\">Ulubiony</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_user\" value=\"$stat[id]\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_movie\" value=\"$podobny_film[id]\">
                            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-md btn--warning\">Dodaj</button>                                        
                </form>                             
                </div>

                // RECORD NR 2
                    <div class=\"movie__btns\" >
                    <form class=\"actionlist\" method=\"post\" >
                            <select name=\"buttonaction\"  class=\"actionlist\" id=\"wybrana_opcja\">
                              <option value=\"watchlater\">Do obejrzenia</option>
                              <option value=\"watched\">Obejrzany</option>
                              <option value=\"favorite\">Ulubiony</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_user\" value=\"$stat[id]\">
                            <input type=\"hidden\" class=\"id_movie\" value=\"$podobny_film[id]\">
                                <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-md btn--warning\">Dodaj</button>                                        
                    </form>                             
                    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('form.actionlist').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var wybor = $("#wybrana_opcja option:selected" ).text();
    var id_user = $('.id_user').val();
    var id_movie = $('.id_movie').val();

});
```